# QListWidget with custom widgets - not triggering itemClicked signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have listwidgetitem's that have a custom widget (step_widget) which contains 3 QPushButtons and a QLabel.
When I press one of the buttons in the widget, it is not triggering itemClicked which i need to see the index of the listwidget that was clicked. If i click the QLabel, the signal is triggered and i am able to obtain the index. How can trigger the signal when one of the buttons is pressed? Why does it not trigger?

```
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
stepWidget *step_widget = new stepWidget();
ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item,step_widget);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itemClicked()` signal is not emmited because the `QPushButton` consumes the click event.
There is the simplest solution I've found.
First, in your class `stepWidget` add a signal that will be emitted when any `QPushButton` is clicked, for example:

```
signals:
    void widgetClicked();
```

Then connect the `clicked()` signal of every `QPushButton` with that signal. This code is in the constructor of the widget `stepWidget`:

```
connect(ui->pushButton1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &stepWidget::widgetClicked);
connect(ui->pushButton2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &stepWidget::widgetClicked);
connect(ui->pushButton3, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &stepWidget::widgetClicked);
```

To test it I added 10 widgets to a `QListWidget` that reside in the `MainWindow` class. You must connect that signal to a slot (in this case I use a C++11 Lambda Function, but you can create a slot instead, it's fine) where you establish the current item as the item under the widget. This code is located in the constructor of `MainWindow`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem;
    stepWidget *step_Widget = new stepWidget;
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item, step_Widget);
    connect(step_Widget, &stepWidget::widgetClicked, [=]() {
        ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
    });
}
```

Now, this will **not** make the `itemClicked()` signal to be emitted because the user not clicked the item. But I advice you to connect instead the signal `currentRowChanged()` as it will be emitted with this code and also it has the advantage that it allows you to directly obtain the row. Once you have the row you can obtain the item and the widget, evidently.
However, this procedure has the inconvenient that the `currentRowChanged()` signal will be emitted even when the user selects a row with the keyboard or when the user press and slide the mouse over the `QListWidget` without releasing it.
On workaround could be, for example, using a flag as an attribute for your `MainWindow` class that is always `false` except during this connection:

```
connect(ste_pWidget, &stepWidget ::widgetClicked, [=]() {
    buttonPressed = true;
    ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
    buttonPressed = false;
});
```

Then you must manipulate two signals from the `QListWidget`: `clicked()` and `currentRowChanged()`. I choose `clicked()` instead of `itemClicked()` because it gives almost directly access to the row:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Row clicked: %1").arg(index.row()), 1000);
}

void MainWindow::on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(int currentRow)
{
    if (buttonPressed) {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Row clicked: %1").arg(currentRow), 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: connect(step_Widget, &stepWidget::widgetClicked, [=]() {
        ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
    });
How did you connect it like this? Is this defining the slot right in the connection itself? It did not compile for me. Says widgetClicked is protected. I made it a signal in stepWidget.

Comment: It compiles fine for me. It's the Qt5 connection style. Which version of Qt are you using? You may want to upgrade to a latest version. Connect using the Qt4 macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` is deprecated but still supported in Qt5, however, it's likely to be removed in Qt6. If you press ALT+RETURN inside a Qt4-style `connect`, it will show you an option to morph it into a Qt5-style `connect` statement. Also, Qt5-style connect has several advantages: **1.** It's faster. **2.** Can be checked at compile-time, not at runtime as old styles. **3.** It allows using C++11 Lambda functions.

Comment: I realize that it works for me even when I put the `signals:` declarations in the same block as the `protected` declarations. You problem may reside on the version of Qt you are using or in the data you want to access from the lambda. Inside the square parenthesis you place the data that you want to access from the Lambda function. Try changing the `=` for a `&` (ampersand). Of course you can also create a separate slot to manipulate the signal. You not have to stick with the Lambda if you don't know how to use it or simply you don't want to use it.

Comment: See this: [Qt Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Answer (score 0):

what you can simply do is, make your qpushbutton to qlabel and then qpushbutton will become clickable.
You can then override this method :- on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item) for double click on qpushbutton.
I tried it & it worked perfectly, its quite simple workaround.